# A ShowBits Class in java from "Java: A beginner's Guide"

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am learning java from a book "Java: A beginner's Guide" by Herbert Schildt. I was compiling a code from that book which can print the bit pattern of any number. here is the code:

```
class ShowBits{
    int numbits;

    ShowBits(int n){
        numbits = n;
    }

    void show(long val){
        long mask = 1;

        mask<<=numbits-1;

        int spacer=0;
        for(;mask!=0;mask>>>=1){
            if(val & mask) System.out.print("1");
            else System.out.print("0");
            spacer++;
            if((spacer % 8)==0){
                System.out.print(" ");
                spacer=0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But it is giving this error:

> error: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to boolean
>             if(val & mask) System.out.print("1");

How to avoid the error?
and how the compiler understands when & is used as a logical operator and when it is used as a bitwise operator.

Comment: what line is the error on?

Comment: It looks at the types of its operands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.  your problem is with this line here

```
if(val & mask)
```

you need to actually make the comparison.  like this:

```
if((val & mask) != 0)
```

this is neither c nor is it javascript.  you can't use numbers like they're booleans.  you need to use actual booleans.

Comment: I am from a c++ background... so I thought if(condition) statement; will be same as if(condition !=0) statement;

Comment: @m.souvik That is why C++ programs break so often and get so many security vulnerabilities.  (Just my biased opinion...)

Comment: @m.souvik in java, `val & mask` is not a condition.  it is an expression which evaluates to a `long` int.

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise operator will return a `long` so you have to compare with something. Just check if it is non zero.

```
if((val & mask) != 0)
```