# Java: left shift

Tags: java

So I am reading "Java : a beginner's guide" and there is code like this :

```
class ShowBits{
    int numbits;

    ShowBits(int n){
        numbits = n;
    }

    void show(long val){
        long mask = 1;

        mask<<=numbits-1;

        int spacer=0;
        for(;mask!=0;mask>>>=1){
            if(val & mask) != 0) System.out.print("1");
            else System.out.print("0");
            spacer++;
            if((spacer % 8)==0){
                System.out.print(" ");
                spacer=0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470534/a-showbits-class-in-java-from-java-a-beginners-guide) on why this person's code wasn't working.

However, I don't understand the purpose of the first initial left shift that

> left-shifts a 1 into the proper position

I do not even know what that means and why you need `numbits - 1` - and then the right shift in the for loop. I have been thinking the right shift is for going down the code to put the `1`s and `0`s, but I do not understand the purpose of the left shift. Can someone please explain? With perhaps an example.

Comment: To understand, you need to step through the method with debugger (or just using pen and paper!), and *looking at the numbers in binary*. When you see the individual bits, it should be clear what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you quoted looks awful and should not be in a book.

- `ShowBits` is a bad class name; it doesn't follow the Java naming conventions.
- The whole class is bloated. This functionality (printing the bits of a `long` value) fits nicely into a simple `static` method.
- When you set `numbits` to a number that is not divisible by 8, the output is misleading, since the bits are grouped from the left side, not from the right side.
- The mask should simply be initialized as `1L << (numbits - 1)` (with the proper spacing, and not with a paragraph in between.
- Since the variable `spacer` is reset to 0, the `%` (modulo) operator is unnecessary.

The books of Herbert Schildt are usually full of errors, please avoid reading them.

---

To answer your actual question: an `int` has 32 bits. When you write it down in binary, it looks like this:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

For printing a binary number, the code uses a bitmask to extract each bit on its own. The bitmask gets the following values, one after another:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00010000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000
...
```

The first value in this series is constructed by starting at 1:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

This 1 is shifted to the left (using the `<<` operator) by `numbits - 1` times. So when `numbits` is 32 (as in my whole example), the 1 will end up in the leftmost position:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand the left and right shift, but I do not understand that code; However, you're telling me it's poorly written code, so I'll just forget about. I understand the concept of left and right shifts. Do you have any books you can recommend other than Herbert Schildt's book?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any Java beginner books. Sorry.

Comment: I just had a quick look into Head First Java, 2nd Edition, and it really looks great. All the concepts are explained as simple as possible, yet as precise as a language lawyer could possibly request it.

Comment: I learnt Java in 1998, and there was a book from the German dpunkt publisher. I think it was a good book, but I wouldn't recommend it anymore because the Java language has changed much since then.